# Where to get sphinxcontrib.autohttp.flask?

Tags: python, flask

I am looking to generate automatic documentation for the REST API of a Flask project. I can't locate the sphinx extension sphinxcontrib.autohttp.flask anywhere and it does not seem to come bundled with sphinx. When I run sphinx I get :

```
Extension error:
Could not import extension sphinxcontrib.autohttp.flask (exception: No module named sphinxcontrib.autohttp.flask)
```

Can somebody give me a pointer to where to find it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `sphinxcontrib.autohttp.flask` module lives in the `sphinxcontrib.httpdomain` contrib extension which you can find here https://bitbucket.org/birkenfeld/sphinx-contrib or you can install it directly using pip like this:

```
pip install sphinxcontrib-httpdomain
```